# Application Loader Rejects My Stencyl App

Tags: ios, publishing, application-loader, stencyl

I have just published my app .ipa file using stencyl to my desktop, then I have tried submitting it through application loader. However, after it gets to "verifying assets with itunes connect" it rejects my app with error ITMS-90163, "Invalid code signing entitlements". I have no idea how to fix this because I published my apps .ipa through stencyl, and all the solutions require going into xcode which I can't do because you can't publish games made with stencyl through xcode.

Can anyone give me any insight into what is causing these problems ? That would be GREATLY appreciated! Thanks so much!

Here is a screen shot to the error I get.

http://s2.postimg.org/gqc6nr6dl/Screen_Shot_2015_02_19_at_6_06_56_pm.png

Answer (score -1):

Don't know about Stencyl but most likely you are building the app using a developer profile while you need to build the app using a distribution profile in order to submit to the App Store.

Comment: I have double checked that all the profiles I am using are distribution, what could it be? I have tried creating new profiles but nothing has worked?

Comment: Verify that in your keychain the distribution certificate is valid / green. You need to create that certificate on the same mac as you are using for distribution.